# How to plot multiple swarmplots in a single figure?

Tags: python, seaborn, swarmplot

I would like to plot multiple swarmplots in a single figure. I think swarmplot is one of the seaborn plots that should be able to do this, as it takes an `axes` keyword. However (with a freshly updated anaconda, matplotlib and seaborn) the following code :

```
import seaborn as sb
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
tips = sb.load_dataset("tips")
f, ax = plt.subplots(2,2)
sb.swarmplot(x="size", y="total_bill", data=tips, axes=ax[0,0])
```

Gives the following error (at the end of a long traceback):

```
ValueError: Can not reset the axes.  You are probably trying to re-use an artist in more than one Axes which is not supported
```

I Googled and can't find any mention of this error. Is it not possible to draw a `swarmplot` into a subplot?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use `ax=`, not `axes=`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Strangely (to me) `axes=` works when a figure has a single axis.

Comment: Keyword arguments get passed through to `plt.scatter`. It looks like that does something with `axes`, though I'm not sure what.

Comment: It might just be calling `plt.figure.gca` internally and doing nothing with `axes`.